# Browser extension to mute a thread on Stack Exchange

Tags: chrome, stack-exchange

I am looking for a browser extension (preferably Chrome) that can mute any activity on a Stack Exchange thread (i.e., prevent the user from receiving notifications triggered by activity on a particular page), just like when muting a conversation in Gmail.

Comment: by thread do you mean question page? so if you mute a question, anything linking to that question shouldn't appear?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ correct~~